# Is there a Firefox add-on that enables emacs keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: linux, firefox, emacs, firefox-extensions

For example, I'd love to be able to press ctrl-a to get to the beginning of a line in an input field and ctrl-k to delete that line, etc.

P.S. Not sure if it matters, but I use Arch Linux.

Comment: [You can use Emacs to edit textareas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386560/789593).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this should be what you want: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/
and of course you can customize the bindings if need be.

Comment: Alas, at the present moment you could comfortably write a text with it only in English. Because when you switch keyboard layout to something else, all the «Meta…» combinations stops working *(e.g. «M+f»)*.

Answer (score 8):

[KeySnail](https://github.com/mooz/keysnail/wiki/) also looks extremely interesting.

(In fact, after a cursory look at both that and Firemacs, I would say that KeySnail looks like the more comprehensive of the two by far.)

Other useful links:

- [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) extension for Firefox.
- [Mozilla](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Mozilla) page at the EmacsWiki.
- [Edit with Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Edit_with_Emacs) extension for Chrome.
- [EmacsClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) page at the EmacsWiki, for other client tricks.
- [Conkeror](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Conkeror): A Mozilla-based web browser with Emacs-like functionality.
- [Use Emacs keybindings everywhere](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2006/01/10/emacs-keybindings-everywhere).

Comment: It have actually the same problem as the «Firemacs»: the «Meta…» combinations stops working after switching layout, and of course it have no «C-\» combination to switch the layout in a friendly for the addon way.

Answer (score 2):

Not a plugin, but you may get some mileage out of [conkeror](http://www.conkeror.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox normally uses the GTK settings for key bindings.  You can just turn on Emacs bindings there GTK-wide.  See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_%28Firefox%29#GNU.2FLinux

Answer (score 0):

Under xfce4, go to:

Settings / Settings Editor / xsettings / Gtk / KeyThemeName

Click Edit property

Change value to Emacs

Save